# Kotlin: Override parent job of coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to migrate the following function to new `Coroutine` of `Kotlin 1.3`:

```
fun launchUI(strategy: CancelStrategy, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit): Job {
    return launch(context = UI, parent = strategy.jobs, block = block)
}
```

But new `GlobalScope.launch` function doesn't have `parent` parameter. Documentation says:

> The parent job is inherited from a `CoroutineScope` as well, but it
>   can also be overridden with corresponding `coroutineContext` element.

But I don't know how to override parent job. I have implemented it like this for now but I am not sure if it will work the same way:

```
fun launchUI(strategy: CancelStrategy, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit): Job {
    val job = GlobalScope.launch(context = Dispatchers.Main, block = block)
    strategy.jobs.invokeOnCompletion {
        job.cancel()
    }
    return job
}
```

Can anyone help me?

**UPDATE:**

```
class CancelStrategy(owner: LifecycleOwner, val jobs: Job) : LifecycleObserver {

    init {
        owner.lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    fun onDestroy() {
        jobs.cancel()
    }
}
```

Comment: what is `CancelStrategy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second example is correct. You can use `plus` to add the job as a parent job for the new coroutine.

```
fun launchUI(strategy: CancelStrategy, block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> Unit): Job {
    return GlobalScope.launch(context = Dispatchers.Main + strategy.jobs, block = block)
}
```

But the usage of `GlobalScope` is discouraged. It would be better to create an own `CoroutineScope`. Your `CancelStrategy` looks like a good candidate.

```
class CancelStrategy(owner: LifecycleOwner, val jobs: Job) : LifecycleObserver, CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + jobs

    init {
        owner.lifecycle.addObserver(this)
    }

    @OnLifecycleEvent(Lifecycle.Event.ON_DESTROY)
    fun onDestroy() {
        jobs.cancel()
    }
}
```

Now you can start your coroutines like this:

```
cancelStrategy.launch { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to have is called "structured concurrency" by aligning the lifecycle of your coroutines to some UI component.

Have a look at this documentation: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/ui/coroutines-guide-ui.md#structured-concurrency-lifecycle-and-coroutine-parent-child-hierarchy

Instead of using `GlobalScope`, you should consider implementing your own scope and maintaining a `Job` their, which you can cancel to cancel all your children as well.

Here's a simplified example:

```
class Activity : CoroutineScope {
    lateinit var job: Job //tied to lifecycle of Activity
    fun create() {
        job = Job()
    }

    fun destroy() {
        //will cancel all child jobs as well
        println("cancel $job and all ${job.children.toList().size} children")
        job.cancel()
    }

    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Default + job + CoroutineName("MyActivityContext")

    fun doSomething() {
       //we launch in the outer scope of Activity
       launch {
          //...
       }
    }
}
```